# How to take stack samples using `perf` based on wall-clock time

Tags: performance, perf, profiling, perf-event

I am trying to use Linux's `perf_events` framework to investigate an issue with an application on one of our servers. Based on my reading about the `perf` tool, collecting stacks is relatively straightforward.

I want to know if it's possible to simply use the wall-time as a kind of event to collect stacks every N seconds.

The current command I've been using is:

```
perf record -e cycles -T -o <dir>/samples.data -F 1 --call-graph dwarf -T -p <pid>
```

From my current understanding, this command will sample every 1 second (`-F 1`) and grab the stacks (`-g`) from the process (`-p <pid>`) until the perf command is terminated with a signal.

But based on the data I collect, it seems like there is more than one set of samples per second? So, I think I am misinterpreting or misunderstanding something about the way `perf` collects samples.

Also, what if I wanted to record stacks every 2, 5, or 10 seconds to reduce the amount of data collected? Is there a way to achieve that with `perf`?